# jQuery selector to grab cells in the same column

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a multirow, multicolumn table, how can I select all cells in the same *column* as any arbitrary cell (e.g. a cell that is clicked on).

Something like:

```
$("td").click(function(){
    var columnNo = $(this).columnNo?
    $(this).closest("table").find("tr td:eq("+columnNo+")").css("color", "red");
});
```

I need to do this without naming the columns individually. E.g. it should work on simple generic `table` markup without extra classes or IDs..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your attempt is right, all you need to do is use [`.index`](http://api.jquery.com/index) to find the column number—the index of the `<td>` within the row. You also need to use the [nth-child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector) to match the column indices of the other `<td>` elements.

```
$("td").click(function(){
    var columnNo = $(this).index();
    $(this).closest("table")
        .find("tr td:nth-child(" + (columnNo+1) + ")")
        .css("color", "red");
});
```

Comment: (I'm not the downvoter, but I have a question:)

The `.eq()` as you have it now will only get the _nth_ element from _all_ the `td`s that match, thus only will get the one on the first row. 
I think it needs an `each()` to make it work? Something like ...`find("tr").each(function(){this.find("td").eq(columnNo)});`. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: @brentonstrine Oops. You're right, `.eq` won't work, but you don't need a loop. Use the [`nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector) selector instead.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using the jQuery `eq` method.

```
var $tds = $("td"); // get all tds beforehand, so jquery doesn't 
                    // need to hit the DOM every click

$("td").on("click", function () {
    var position = $(this).index(),
        $tdsInColumn = $tds.filter(":nth-child(" + index + ")");

    // manipulate $tdsInColumn in any way
    $tdsInColumn.addClass("selected");
});
```

Not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing so, but it is the solution I came up with when faced with the same problem a while back.

## Reference

[jQuery.eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: @mplungjan good suggestion, updated. Wondering if there is a less messy way to get the tds, possibly beforehand? let me try that and update the answer.

Comment: This is not how [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) works. *Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.* It returns a jQuery object, *never* a number.

Comment: It looks like `.eq()` returns an object instead of an index number. nbrooks suggestion of using `index()` seems to make more sense to me.

Comment: Ah, yes. Eq returns a jQuery object containing the list of matched elements. Index should be used to find the offset. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @mplungjan just found that `eq` will not in fact work, the `nth-child` selector must be used. Eq will get the element that occurs at the specified index within the entire list of td's. It does so regardless of trs.

Comment: You were right with your initial use of `nth-child`, it's needed to get more than just the first row, see `nbrooks` answer. I've upvoted you but I think he gets the answer since he pointed out the need for `index()` first.

Comment: Right, I have updated my answer, and no worries on the answer.

Comment: I did not check the docs to see if .eq() would return the index - some jQuery statements are interchangeable. I myself was thinking of parent().nextUntil($(this),"td").length or size() but discarded the attempt when I saw your initial nth/eq suggestion