# Using nextUntil to find index of current cell

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

Here is the question I tried to learn from

[jQuery selector to grab cells in the same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061123/jquery-selector-to-grab-cells-in-the-same-column)

Before any of the answers using index and nth-child had been proposed I was thinking along the lines of counting number of cells before $(this) cell - e.g.

```
var columnNo = parentRow.nextUntil($(this),"td").length;
console.log(columnNo); // gives 0 - what am I missing?
parentTable.find("tr td:nth-child(" + (columnNo+1) + ")")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/JUt4F/

Questions:

1. why does the nextUntil not give the length of the preceding cells?

<s>2. why does the click only work once?</s>

Please note that I know (before asking this) I can use index. I just wanted to fix my script to explore nextUntil

**UPDATE**: I seem to mix nextAll and nextUntil and likely imagined some kind of nextAllUntil

Comment: nextUntil searches all siblings, not child. Also the first argument should be this, not $(this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nextUntil()` method will find the first `td` tag in the parent row. With that logic, you're only going to select the first cell in each row. The click is working everytime--you're just coloring the same column red over and over.

What you need to do is search for all `td` tags on the parent row and use jQuery's `index()` method to identify the position of the clicked cell in that row.

A very small tweak will fix the problem:

```
$("td").on("click",function(){
    var parentTable = $(this).closest("table");
    var parentRow = $(this).parent();
    console.log(parentRow);
    var columnNo = parentRow.find('td').index($(this));
    console.log(columnNo);
    parentTable.find("tr td:nth-child(" + (columnNo+1) + ")")
        .css("color", "red");
});​
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JUt4F/15/**

Comment: On OSX Chrome I only got one console.log for some reason. Now I do get the click

Comment: The first console.log isn't going to log anything, `parentRow` isn't text or a number. Try doing `console.log(typeof(parentRow))` or `console.log(parentRow.html())`

Comment: In my Chome I actually do get a response for the first console.log: `[<tr>, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: <td>]`

Comment: Can I use nextUntil plus length to find the index

Comment: No, `nextUntil` will only select one element (the first match it finds)--therefore the length will always be 1.

Comment: Ahhhh - Thanks. nextAllUntil was the non-existing statement I was looking for :)