# Select all <td> elements that "belong" to specific <th> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select all `<td>` elements that are in same column as `<th>` element that has `data-something` as attribute.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th data-column="A">Column A</th>
        <th data-column="B">Column B</th>
        <th data-column="C">Column C</th>
        <th data-column="D">Column D</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data A1</td>
        <td>Data B1</td>
        <td>Data C1</td>
        <td>Data D1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data A2</td>
        <td>Data B2</td>
        <td>Data C2</td>
        <td>Data D2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data A3</td>
        <td>Data B3</td>
        <td>Data C3</td>
        <td>Data D3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data A4</td>
        <td>Data B4</td>
        <td>Data C4</td>
        <td>Data D4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data A5</td>
        <td>Data B5</td>
        <td>Data C5</td>
        <td>Data D5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For example button for data-column A is clicked, I want to select all elements that belong to column A.

I made quick table for visual example of table:

[image]

Vanilla or jQuery (or some lightweight library), I am open for both solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Try [How to select a table column with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375625/how-to-select-a-table-column-with-jquery) or [jQuery selector to grab cells in the same column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061123/jquery-selector-to-grab-cells-in-the-same-column)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks, both seem very useful!

Comment: Would you ever worry about `colspan > 1`?

Comment: @4castle not in my case. luckily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('table tr td:nth-child('+$("table th[data-column="desired value"]").index() + 1+')')
```

Comment: Is it possible to use similar `css` only selector ?

Comment: Sorry I have not enough knowledge of CSS to extract the order of a column @Muflix