# How to highlight a column in html table on click using js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a javascript which will highlight the column in an html table on click.As the below working example for row highlight i tried to use the same with table.columns but table.columns doesn't exist.Is there any was to highlight the column in html table using jquery?

Working code for highlighting row:
    
        
            Table Highlight POC

```
        <script>

            function highlight() {
                var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
                for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                    table.rows[i].onclick = function () {
                        if (!this.hilite) {
                            this.origColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
                            this.style.backgroundColor = '#BCD4EC';
                            this.hilite = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            this.style.backgroundColor = this.origColor;
                            this.hilite = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        </script>
        <style>


            table {
                border-spacing: 0px;
            }

            td {
                border: 1px solid #bbb;
                padding: 0.2em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="dataTable">
            <tr onclick="highlight()"><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td></tr>
            <tr onclick="highlight()"><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td></tr>
            <tr onclick="highlight()"><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061123/jquery-selector-to-grab-cells-in-the-same-column) you can see how to select all cells from the same column as the one clicked. Then all you need to do is to set the backgroundColor to all those cells.

Comment: Your question is about highlighting column, but your code seem to suggest trying to select rows. Which one is it you're trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
$('td').on('click', function() {
    var $currentTable = $(this).closest('table');
    var index = $(this).index();
    $currentTable.find('td').removeClass('selected');
    $currentTable.find('tr').each(function() {
        $(this).find('td').eq(index).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Just put this on your JS file and it will work on all available tables independently. In case you want to use it only on a specific table, just change the initial selector to `$('#myTable td')`.

Also dont forget to add the `.selected{ background-color: #ace; }` class in yor css file.

Here is the [working example](http://codepen.io/fisniq/pen/LkyyjJ).

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```js
$("#dataTable tr td").click(function() {
  //Reset
  $("#dataTable td").removeClass("highlight");
  //Add highlight class to new column
  var index = $(this).index();
  $("#dataTable tr").each(function(i, tr) {
   $(tr).find('td').eq(index).addClass("highlight");
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataTable">
  <tr><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

A fork Fisnik Tahiri solution to support also the tr selection (based on css or jquery if you preferir)

css:

```
.selected{ background-color: #ace; }
tr:hover{ background-color: #ace; }
```

Js:

```
$('td').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var $currentTable = $(this).closest('table');
    //var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var index = $(this).index();

    //clean
    $currentTable.find('td').removeClass('selected');


    //select row if you want use js
    //$currentTable.find('tr').removeClass('selected');
    //$row.addClass('selected');


    //select column
    $currentTable.find('tr').each(function() {
       $(this).find('td').eq(index).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

[working example](https://codepen.io/avol-io/pen/ZJWYMJ)

Comment: How I wrote: "to support also the tr selection"
this is possible by this css row :
tr:hover{ background-color: #ace; }

or if someone prefer a jquery solution (have to remove comments from this two line)
$currentTable.find('tr').removeClass('selected');
$row.addClass('selected');

Answer (score -1):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>onclick highlight</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     $( ".table tr" ).click(function(){
         $(".table tr" ).css("background-color","white");
         $(this).css("background-color","green");
     });
 });

 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
    <table class="table">
       <tr>
           <td>Date1</td>
           <td>Date2</td>
           <td>Date3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
           <td>Date1</td>
           <td>Date2</td>
           <td>Date3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Date1</td>
          <td>Date2</td>
          <td>Date3</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: trying to select column...not row