# Dynamically Prevent Socket.io Timeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, socket.io

I am trying to prevent my Socket.io client from disconnecting to my server due to heartbeat timeouts because my client is spending too much time manipulating the DOM.

In general, the Socket.io timeouts are perfectly fine for my application. There is just one instance in which the client *might* want to generate a table of the data they're using. The data is of variable size, depending on which dataset the client is using, so it could be small (which isn't a problem) or be really big. I'm focusing on when the data is so big that it creates a timeout for the Socket.io heartbeats.

Because the data is of variable length and is chosen after the client/server connection has been initialized, I need to be able to dynamically manipulate the amount of time permitted for a timeout to occur. In other words, since the timeouts are generally fine except for this *one* specific instance, I would like to increase the amount of time permitted for a timeout based on how the DOM manipulation is going and reset it to a normal timeout after the DOM manipulation has completed.

A bit of extra info to toss in here is that my server's disconnect code kills a Python process spawned in to handle some heavy data computation. This process is tied to that specific client. Therefore, if the client/server communication is broken, then the client's communication with this Python process is also broken, meaning the client is effectively useless if it cannot maintain its connection to the server. This means that a simple "reconnect" is insufficient (unless I can reconnect back to the same Socket.io room/session before the server decides it should kill the Python process).

**Anyone know how to properly manipulate Socket.io heartbeat timeouts dynamically? Or any way I can prevent the timeout in the first place during lengthy DOM manipulations?** Extra bonus if there's a way I can do this DOM manipulation without hanging up the client and maintaining its interactivity while the table is being generated!

Code/Browser versions:

- Node.js: 8.16.2 (I know this is old, but we're relying on a package that is not compatible with newer versions of Node.js)
- socket.io: ^2.2.0
- d3: 3.5.17 (?)

  - The link I have to d3 is http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js  I know it's old, but I remember trying to upgrade once, which broke everything terribly, so I'm scared to change since that would mean updating thousands of lines of code across my entire app
- JQuery: 1.12.1 (which is also old, I know)
- Chrome: 78.0.3904.70 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Stuff I've tried:

- Switched form using for loops to using the forEach function to iterate over the data I'm parsing to create the table (since a friend of mine suggested that this may be a little more forgiving for my heartbeats, but I haven't noticed a difference)
- Used setTimeout to try to permit the client enough time to send/receive heartbeat messages (which I tested for up to 1s timeouts, which I figured should be more than generous enough to maintain the heartbeat)
- Used async functions to try to effectively get parallel threads going (one of which I hoped would handle the heartbeats)
- Emitting heartbeat signals myself, either using `socket.emit("ping")`, `socket.emit("pong")`, or my own `socket.emit("heartbeat")`
- Attempted to manipulate properties of the server's io object to force a longer amount of time permitted before a timeout is triggered (which I couldn't find a proper way to do if there is a way)
- Attempted to disable the disconnect functions dynamically for both client and server (which doesn't seem to have any effect; see code below)

Here's the code I have on the client side that is causing the issue (with  my latest attempt at trying to disable the effect of the "disconnect" messages):

```
var shouldDisconnect = true;

socket.on('disconnect', disconnectFunc(shouldDisconnect));

function disconnectFunc(shouldDisconnect) {
    return function() {
        if (shouldDisconnect) {
            d3.selectAll("div").remove();
            d3.select("body").append("h3").text("Your communication with the server " +
                "has been interrupted. Please refresh this page to reconnect.");
        }
    }
}

// Similar logic in manipulating a shouldDisconnect variable and the
// socket.on("disconnect") callbacks is repeated server-side. This
// approach doesn't seem to have any effect on when I see timeouts.



// Prevent the server from disconnecting
shouldDisconnect = false;
socket.removeListener("disconnect", disconnectFunc(shouldDisconnect));
socket.on("disconnect", disconnectFunc(shouldDisconnect));
socket.emit("setDiconnect", false);

// Create a table of the raw CSV data that we have been provided
var rawDataDiv = rawTableContainer.append("div")
    .attr("id", "rawDataDiv")
    .attr("class", "col-md-12")
    .style("width", function () {
        return (this.parentNode.clientWidth - 60) + "px";
    })
    .style("height", "500px")
    .style("border", "solid black 1px")
    .style("margin", "15px 20px 15px")
    .style("overflow", "scroll");

var rawDataTable = rawDataDiv.append("table")
    .attr("id", "rawDataTable")
    .attr("class", "table");

// Sort the keys, leaving the specified key as the first key
var dataKeys = Object.keys(csvContents[0]);
dataKeys.splice(dataKeys.indexOf(firstKey), 1);
dataKeys = [firstKey].concat(dataKeys.sort());

// Sort the objects
csvContents.sort((a, b)=> (a[dataKeys[0]] > b[dataKeys[0]]) ? 1 : -1 );

// Create the first row of the table
var firstRow = rawDataTable.append("thead").append("tr");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dataKeys.length; i++) {
    firstRow.append('th').attr("scope", "col").append("p").text(dataKeys[i]);
}

// Create each individual row of the table
rawDataTable = rawDataTable.append("tbody");
csvContents.forEach(async function(csvRow) {
    var nextRow = rawDataTable.append("tr")

        // Highlight row when mousing over
        .on("mouseover", function() {
            d3.select(this).classed("selected-row", true)
                .selectAll("td").style("background-color", "yellow");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function() {
            d3.select(this).classed("selected-row", false)
                .selectAll("td").style("background-color", "white");
        });

        // Create each entry for the current row
        dataKeys.forEach(async function(dataKey, i) { setTimeout( function() {
            var td;
            if (dataKey === dataKeys[0]) {
                td = nextRow.append("th").attr("scope", "row");
            }
            else {
                td = nextRow.append('td')

                    // Highlight column when mousing over
                    // Code adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131000/how-to-highlight-a-column-in-html-table-on-click-using-js-or-jquery
                    .on("mouseover", function() {
                        var index = $(this).index();
                        $("#rawDataTable tr").each(function(i, tr) {
                            $(tr).find('td').eq(index-1).css("background-color", "yellow");
                        });
                    })
                    .on ("mouseout", function() {
                        var index = $(this).index();
                        $("#rawDataTable tr").each(function(j, tr) {
                            $(tr).find('td').eq(index-1).each(function(k, td) {
                                if (!$(tr).hasClass("selected-row")) {
                                    $(td).css("background-color", "white");
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });

                // Add an ID and tooltip for each td
                var observationName = csvRow[firstKey];
                td.attr("id", "o-" + observationName.replace(/\/|<|>|\.| |'/g, "-") + "--a-" +  dataKey.replace(/\/|<|>|\.| |'/g, "-")).attr("title", observationName + ", " +  dataKey);
            }

            td.append("p").text(csvRow[dataKey]);

    }, 200) });
});

socket.removeListener("disconnect", disconnectFunc(shouldDisconnect));
shouldDisconnect = true;
socket.on("disconnect", disconnectFunc(shouldDisconnect));
socket.emit("setDiconnect", true);
```

Comment: websockets time out after a minute, and I'm pretty sure your synchronous DOM manipulations don't take _that_ long to run? Any normal page use, even one where updates block the thread for a full second (which would already be pretty incredible) should not be anywhere near hitting a websocket timeout?

Comment: Actually, they could take MUCH longer to run. Generating the full table for one of my datasets can take several minutes (41 rows + 875 columns). There is potential for larger datasets as well.

Comment: Why would you make the server run that operation, though? Your server should always stay available, stuff like that should _not_ block it. Have a separate task scheduler that constructs your data, and has an easily checked way to see whether that task has finished (a file in a shared dir, sqlite entry, full blown SQL server, what have you) so that the client can ask for the data, the server checks if it exists, if it doesn't has a different process generate it, and once it exists, sends a websocket message "here's that data you wanted a while back".

Comment: The above code is client-side (not server-side) code that is happening within a callback for the message that contains the data to generate the table. The callback itself seems to run very quickly; I generate a button within this callback to have the user indicate when they want the table since it can be so expensive/time consuming to generate. The button appears almost immediately after the user selects their desired dataset, so the issue is down to the DOM manipulation to create the table. My server is still able to respond to other requests without an issue.

Comment: That sounds like you're focussing on a red herring. The real problem here is absolutely "why is my DOM generation taking so long", because JS will happily convert a million element array into a table in under a second. I'd strongly advise creating a [mcve] of _that_ part of your code for yourself first (hardcode everything, including the data - big enough to take several seconds, small enough to not lead to a megabytes-big .html file) and then you probably want to ask a new question based on your findings around that code rather than asking about websocket timeouts.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between a minimal reproducible example and the code I have above. The code above is generating the table based on the data passed to it. I could create a separate interface that has just the table that it builds based on static JSON, but that seems like overkill since I already narrowed down the issue to this code. Nothing else is happening while this code is running.

So, yes, my issue could be solved by answering "why is my DOM generation taking so long," but it seems to me like my code is efficient. Do you have any ideas how I can make it more efficient?

Comment: I should also mention that I have tried a number of methods for improving performance of my DOM generation before I started trying to manipulate Socket.io timeouts. I tried using Workers (but they can't manipulate the DOM directly), async functions, the timeouts, switching to the forEach method instead of my own for loops... Everything I tried either didn't work/run or had no noticeable improvement over my previous code.

Comment: One thing you really want to try is to create that table _outside_ of the current DOM: even single `append` that you call on the live DOM causes a full document reflow, which is going to slow things down an incredible amount. Create a detached table (e.g. `const table = $("<table>");`), run through your data and build that out, without the active document trying to update on every insert and append, and then only once you're done, add that new table to the DOM. There's also a lot of async going on here that probably isn't helping: `async` is only synchronous if there's an `await`.

Comment: So a more responsive solution would probably be something akin to preparing most of your table and then calling something like `(function addNextRow() { if (!datarows.length) { return addTableToDom(); } const row = datarows.unshift(); addRowToTable(row); setTimeout(addNextRow, 50); })();`, so that your code builds out your table one row at a time, but with micropaues in between calls, giving the browser time to do "whatever needs to be done" in between rows, including handling websocket keepalives, ending in a call to `addTableToDom()` to finalise everything once the table's done building.

Comment: It is MUCH faster now if I create the entire table in raw text and append it that way. Afterwards, I use d3 to add in the highlight-on-hover interactions within the table. However, I still think my original question is valid... Even with generating the table faster, large datasets still can cause the heartbeat time outs as d3 adds interactive SVG elements to the DOM and transitions them to their proper locations in the SVG. Therefore, this issue is amplified when initializing the SVGs, but it would be nice if I could set heartbeat timeouts for a client dynamically based on the dataset size

Comment: Hm, d3 should be able to be told to do this "in phases" as well, using a similar technique - the problem of the socket timing out isn't really one about how much ywork ou need to do, but splitting that work up into slices that you quickly run and then hand control back to the JS engine, so that it can consult its schedule tasks and run code that also needs to run, which should lead to the socket having plenty of opportunity to stay open. Can you slice up the d3 work into a "list of DOM nodes" that you can them "empty out" similar to the above data row work?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's an easy way for me to do that... I'm relying heavily on the enter() and exit() events in d3 to maintain my visualized data properly as the user transitions from one view/state to another. Combined with all the interactions and interconnectivity on each SVG element I create (which are also built with d3 and rely on d3 transitions), I think that would be a hard thing to accomplish easily. (Perhaps I'm just approaching a the limits of a "reasonably supported" size for a dataset in my tool... Things are at least better than what they were)

Comment: hm, yeah looking at how those functions work, those are going to block the thread quite effectively... for performance it might be worth moving away from those and using vanilla JS to ensure you have the right number of containers available before running d3.select(..).data(...) - there _are_ a few ways to tweak timeout values, but it's kind of a crapshoot, and depending on the browser, longer timeout values might not even get respected.

Comment: Well, how would I dynamically change the Socket.io heartbeat timeouts? If you know a way, it's worth a shot... I don't think vanilla JS is very realistic for my application, especially since it would involve writing/rewriting thousands of lines of complicated code that otherwise work fine

Comment: You can try to start up your socketio server using custom pingtimeout and pingInterval values (see https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#new-Server-httpServer-options) but that's not something you can set dynamically. enter() and exit() are relatively straightforward to write in plain JS (by comparing your `data.length` and `container.querySelectorAll(`tr`).length` for example), so it might still be worth first trying to see whether that buys you enough of a speedup before resorting to socket timeout fiddling.

Comment: My enter() and exit() functions rely on specific values in the JSON object representation for each piece of data that I'm visualizing since data may be added or removed at the same time. Therefore, just checking the lengths will be insufficient; I will have to loop through everything by hand to check whether the data bound in the DOM is valid and remove that DOM element if it is invalid. It isn't hard, but it is annoying and breaks a lot of the connectivity I have with d3, so I'd rather try socket timeout fiddling, if possible. Rewriting the code to use JS will take time I don't presently have